# Como gerar um contador dentro de um select (SQL server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Preciso fazer um select com um case, caso a condição seja verdadeira preciso usar um contador que sera uma nova coluna, caso contrario o contador sera exibido sem nenhuma alteração, porém não estou conseguindo, tentei com a função ROW_NUMBER mas não deu certo, se alguem puder me ajudar eu agradeço:

```
    declare @c int 
    set @c = 0
    select 
    (
         case when HR_ENTRADA > is null then
         (
             (ROW_NUMBER()over(order by HR_ENTRADA asc)+@c) 
         )
         else
         (
           @c
         )
        end
   )as FALTAS

    from TB_REGISTRO_PONTO
```

Essa query funciona, porem se cair no else, esse contador do row_number tmb acrescenta, e eu não quero isso, eu só quero que ele acrescente se a condição for verdadeira.

Comment: Consegue colocar um exemplo do resultado esperado?

Comment: É um controle de ponto, a query é apenas para verificar se o funcionario tem marcação no horario de entrada, independente de qual horario ele bateu a entrada, ou seja, se nessa coluna não ter nenhum valor (NULL) vai ser uma falta, e o contador acrescenta 1.

Comment: Poderia experimentar trocar a sua lógica para: `case when HR_ENTRADA is null then` nem necessita ter o else. Tem melhores formas de fazer essa contagem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei se entendi bem a pergunta, mas é isso que você quer?

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN {CONDIÇÃO VERDADEIRA} THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FALTAS
FROM
    TB_REGISTRO_PONTO
```

Comment: `SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN HR_ENTRADA is null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FALTAS
FROM
    TB_REGISTRO_PONTO` Aplica essa solução do Paulo

Comment: Mais simples do que eu pensei.

Comment: Foi isso mesmo obrigado!!